# Open file and close file statement positioning: best practice, advantages, disadvantages

Tags: c++, performance, memory, optimization, fortran

I have a code, containing *many* loop iterations, with `open file` and `close file` statements positioned as follows:

- Main loop

  1. do work
  2. open files
  3. write to files
  4. close files
  5. continue work
- end loop

But, an alternative is:

- open files
- Main loop

  1. do work
  2. write to files, [flush]
  3. continue work
- end loop
- close files

Is there a "best practice" to positioning `open file` and `close file` statements containing *many* loop iterations? Are there advantages / disadvantages to each? Will I see performance differences? Memory restrictions? Future development issues down the line?

I'm mainly coding in Fortran (hence the tag), however, I would like to know if this is language dependent or not, since I also program in other languages. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, you should profile your specific code to see what are the bottlenecks. However, in general, opening and closing files is *very* expensive.

Consider the following:

```
def foo():
    f = open('bar.txt', 'w')
    for i in range(1000):
        f.write('a')
    f.close()

def bar():
    for i in range(1000):
        f = open('bar.txt', 'w')
        f.write('a')
        f.close()
```

Let's time it:

```
>>> %timeit foo()
10000 loops, best of 3: 190 µs per loop

>>> %timeit bar()
10 loops, best of 3: 47.8 ms per loop
```

So, opening and closing is extremely expensive.

What are the advantages (or at least mitigating factors) for the constant opens and closes?

1. Less open file descriptors.
2. When you close a file, the data is flushed to it. Of course you could just call `flush`, but that is an expensive operation in itself, and the time differences would become narrower.

If you don't have critical data (i.e., you can just rerun the program if it crashes), and don't have too many open file descriptor problems - few opens and closes will probably be faster.

Comment: he evidently needs to flush in the loop for some reason  (though not explained very well in the question).  Maybe a third case with a flush would be good to add to the timing test.

Comment: Thank you for the practical example. I do need flush for monitoring certain transient data, so thank you for including remarks regarding flush.

Comment: I do wish you included some information about code design. It seems that the slower design may be favorable in certain situations. For example, I want to edit a file while the code is executing, which then imports this data and is used in the simulation. When I try this while the code is open, I get an error: "Error: the process cannot access the file because its being used by another process.".

Comment: @Charlie Right. That could be another consideration (of which I did not think).

Answer (score 3):

If you can do a task outside the loop, you better do it, since every time you add it to the loop queue results in worse performance (n times instead of 1). Therefore, declaring variables or opening files before the loop is better than repeating it with every iteration.

---

- Main loop

  1. do work - **cost:** k * n
  2. open files - **cost:** q * n
  3. write to files - **cost:** r * n
  4. close files - **cost:** s * n
  5. continue work - **cost:** l * n
- end loop

**Total:** n * (k + q + r + s + l)

---

- open files - **cost:** q
- Main loop

  1. do work - **cost:** k * n
  2. write to files - **cost:** r * n
  3. continue work - **cost:** l * n
- end loop
- close files - **cost:** s

**Total:** n * (k + r + l) + q + s

---

`s` and `q` are very expensive, since accessing files on the system disk costs much more time and is very slow compared to accessing variables or performing calculation, since it is needs to get the data from the disk, as opposed to the variables that are stored in the RAM and are easily accessible through the code flow. See more on caching and io buffering for that.

As for performance:

```
$ python -m timeit 'open("hw.txt").read()'
1000 loops, best of 3: 240 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'a=2;b=3;c=a**b'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.15 usec per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for the theoretical answer, I like this viewpoint, and I would have selected this as the answer, however, you haven't included any sort of estimate on how big "q" and "s" are, which is why I accepted the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a task many times (in the loop) versus doing it just once (outside the loop) is obviously going to be more costly - regardless of the language used.